# TSQL Select the min date in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a sample dataset:

```
ID  DATE       STATUS        DURATIONTIME
1  30-08-2017  Done          220
1  30-08-2017  In progress   100
1  29-08-2017  In progress   50
1  28-08-2017  New           10
2  30-08-2017  Done          200
2  30-08-2017  In progress   100
2  29-08-2017  In progress   60
2  29-08-2017  New           50
2  28-08-2017  New           10
```

Result expected:

```
1    60
2    120
```

We want to calculate the sum of the duration times when status is not done and if status is In Progress, then only take the duration for the earliest date.

Here is the query I try:

```
SELECT        ID, SUM(DURATIONTIME) 
FROM          MYDB
WHERE         STATUS <> 'Done'
            AND DURATIONTIME = CASE
                WHEN (STATUS = 'In progress' AND DATE <> min(DATE)) 
                THEN 0
                ELSE DURATIONTIME END 
GROUP BY ID ASC
```

But the query fails... any idea how to rewrite this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` window function

```
SELECT ID,
       Sum(DURATIONTIME)
FROM   (SELECT DENSE_RANK()OVER(partition BY ID, Status ORDER BY DATE asc) Rn,*
        FROM   yourtable
        WHERE  Status in ('New','In progress')) a
WHERE  (Rn = 1 and Status = 'In progress') or Status = 'New'
GROUP  BY ID
```

- [DEMO](http://rextester.com/BIV85746)

Comment: It doesn't work because other statuses can have more than one line for the same ID, I'll edit the dataset

Comment: ok but you don't count the DURATIONTIME of other statuses here.

Comment: @VincentTeyssier - Updated.. check now

Comment: Will this run into a problem if two rows have the same ID, Status of 'In Progress' on the same day? (Dense rank will return 1 for both)

Comment: @CaiusJard - OP had that data.. and removed it.. He needs both the records in case of *Tie*. My initial version is with `Row_Number`

Comment: There cannot be a case in which date and status will be the same, so no problem :)